# LongListSelector change ItemTemplate

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I want to dynamically change the `ItemTemplate` of a `LongListSelector`. I do this by Binding it to a property in my ViewModel:

```
  <toolkit:LongListSelector ItemTemplate="{Binding ItemTemplate}" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" />
```

This works so far. The problem is that if I change the property for the template in my ViewModel then the `LongListSelector` doesn't apply the changed template.

I looked in the debugger, whenever I change the property by using it's setter, then the getter gets called in turn, so the `LongListSelector` reads the new template (but doesn't apply it).

Is this a bug, or is it not possible to change the `ItemTemplate` via a binding?

Comment: Could you clarify why you need this? Often a `DataTemplateSelector` is a better choice, if you need conditional based templating.

Comment: silverlight has no `DataTemplateSelector`, I know there are workarounds but I don't like them...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The LongListSelector ignores changes to its ItemTemplate.  The DependencyProperty definition in LongListSelector looks like this:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsTemplateProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ItemTemplate", typeof(DataTemplate), 
                                     typeof(LongListSelector), 
                                     new PropertyMetadata(null));
```

If you want it to notice changes, you can fetch the source and rebuild it like this:

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsTemplateProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ItemTemplate", typeof(DataTemplate), 
                                     typeof(LongListSelector), 
                                     new PropertyMetadata(null, 
                                                          OnItemsTemplateChanged));

    private static void OnItemsTemplateChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ((LongListSelector)obj).OnItemsTemplateChanged();
    }

    private void OnItemsTemplateChanged()
    {
        _flattenedItems = null;
        if (_isLoaded)
        {
            EnsureData();
        }
    }
```

Comment: it seems that this has been fixed anyway in the August 2011 toolkit