# Adding LongListSelector via code not working

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, longlistselector

I have problems adding a `LongListSelector` via code in Silverlight. Here is the code:

```
PivotItem pi = new PivotItem();
pi.Header = r.Recipe_Title;

LongListSelector lls = new LongListSelector();
lls.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent);
lls.ItemTemplate = App.Current.Resources["CheckboxShoppingItemTemplate"] as DataTemplate;
lls.ListHeaderTemplate = App.Current.Resources["citiesListHeader"] as DataTemplate;
lls.GroupFooterTemplate = App.Current.Resources["citiesListFooter"] as DataTemplate;
lls.GroupHeaderTemplate = App.Current.Resources["groupHeaderTemplate"] as DataTemplate;
lls.GroupItemTemplate = App.Current.Resources["groupItemTemplate"] as DataTemplate;
lls.ItemsSource = r.Ingredients;
pi.Content = lls;
```

The pivot header appears but the list doesn't. I only see the list's Header but nothing else. The footer is also missing although it is correct (i've replaced the header with the footer to see if it is correct, and it is).

Comment: Have you verified that your `App.Current.Resources["x"]` is not null?

Comment: they are not null.. the exact same templates work if i introduce them in xaml

Comment: Which version of the Silverlight Toolkit do you use? There seem to be problems with older versions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7085781/longlistselector-change-itemtemplate

Comment: i have the last one: August 2011

Answer (score 0):

http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/wp7-longlistselector-in-depth--part1-visual-structure-and-api

this should help u.. the content is really good..